# SQL server business intelligence development studio for VS2012/sql server 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, business-intelligence

I'm a beginner with SSIS. I try to launch sql server buisness intelligence development studio but I can't find it obviously it's not installed.

I'm using VS2012 with sql server 2008. I installed this version http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36843 but it's for sql server 2012, I want to keep working with 2008.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Visual Studio 2012 to develop BI applications for SQL server 2008; they are not backwards compatible